# Why are present participles used in this way? Do both passage convey the exact same meaning?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, present-participles

> Extreme heat also depletes the oil’s additives sooner, ***altering***
> the oil’s chemistry and ***preventing*** it from lubricating, cooling
> and protecting as designed."

This is the actual writing piece I have found in a blog post. I usually read more like this and the question always had in my mind.

Here is how I want it to be:

> Extreme heat also depletes the oil’s additives sooner, ***alters***
> the oil’s chemistry and ***prevents*** it from lubricating, cooling,
> and protecting as designed.

Why are present participles used in this way? Do both passage convey the exact same meaning?

Comment: Your version is perfectly valid, but personally I prefer the original. Yours is a somewhat tedious "list" of three consecutive "subject + verb" statements, whereas imho the original is a far more elegant construction with two adverbial elements modifying the most important verb *(**depletes** the additives)*

Comment: ...The rewrite also incorrectly shifts the meaning, because it asserts that "extreme heat" alters the chemistry and hinders correct functionality as per design. Which strictly speaking it *does* - but only as an "indirect consequence" of the ***primary*** effect (that extreme heat ***depletes the additives***).

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. Now it makes more sense. I don't notice a similar formation in our own native language. So I couldn't sometimes figure out what these kinds of sentences indicate. These are oftentimes seen in news articles.  Hoping to get more on that

Answer (score 7):

No, the two versions have different meanings.

The original version can be re-written:

> Extreme heat also depletes the oil’s additives sooner, **which alters** the oil’s chemistry **and prevents** it from lubricating, cooling and protecting as designed.

Here, "which" refers to the depletion of the oil's additives. So in the original version, "extreme heat" depletes, and the depletion alters and prevents.

In your re-written version, the subject "extreme heat" does three things: depletes, alters, and prevents. This isn't the same thing because extreme heat, on its own, doesn't directly alter or prevent. It's the depletion that does those things.

While it would be natural to attribute the alteration and prevention to the extreme heat since it started a chain of events which caused all three, the original sentence does not have this meaning.

Comment: *extreme heat **started a chain of events*** - well put!